# connection.data property is nil in opentok 2.2.3 beta version

Tags: ios, opentok

I am using OpenTok framework for video/audio/chat application. I have tried with opentok version 2.1.7 , 2.2 beta & 2.2.3 bta. Each have their pro's & cons.

2.2.3 beta version, for

```
- (void) session:(OTSession *)session connectionCreated:(OTConnection *)connection
```

**I am getting each property of connection except data. Only data property is nil**. Is there any specific reason or I have to write additional code to get that.

Note: I am getting data property value for 2.2 beta version with same code.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the OpenTok SDK, released June 13, fixed the bug and has connection.data property. http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/